# Should I check if ProgressBar isShowing before dismissing it?

Tags: android

Im dismissing progress dialog when AsyncTask is finished. Should i check isShowing before dismissing it?

I've tried remove this check and it works normally, but may be there are hidden traps?

```
if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
  progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is seems that is checked inside implementation:

```
public void dismiss() {
    if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
        mHandler.post(mDismissAction);
    } else {
        mDismissAction.run();
    }
}

private void dismissDialog() {
    if (mDecor == null || !mShowing) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        mWindowManager.removeView(mDecor);
    } finally {
        mDecor = null;
        mWindow.closeAllPanels();
        onStop();
        mShowing = false;

        sendDismissMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You shouldnt have to check for isShowing to dismiss it. If you dont check for isShowing it will just ignore the dismiss() is the progressbar isnt showing.

But checking for isShowing is a good practice. So it wont hurt to continue to check for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one place in your code that where `dismiss()` is called, then no. You should know if the dialog is showing or not at that time.

I have however experienced some problems with ProgressDialogs and orientation change, which caused the need for have more than one place where the dialog potentially would be dismissed, thus making the `isShowing()` check needed.

Answer (score 0):

check the [source code](http://www.google.co.in/codesearch/p?hl=en#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ProgressDialog.java&exact_package=android&q=progressdialog&type=cs), if it is handled in code you don't have to worry. If no handling is done it is your choice to create more-risky-but-fast or slow-but-safe environment.